# Override done button functionality inappbrowser

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Is it possible to override done button functionality? i need to just hide inappbrowser on done button as when show same the last visit url next time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can hide the Done button in Android (setting option Footer = false) but not in iOS. This makes sense because in Android you have the Back button to close the browser and come back to the app. But iOS does not have back button, so the user needs a graphical button for it.

Second, you can't override the button functionality, but you can add events to the browser, to run your code when something happens, for example when the browser is closed, all of this is explained in the Github page:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

```
browser. addEventListener( "exit", () => {
     // Here do something
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add closebuttoncaption=Done

Example:
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=Done);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).